# Dealing with relative paths when calling Java from Batch file, from C#

Tags: java, c#, batch-file

I have been given a batch file from a vendor. This batch file runs a Java program, and the java command is executed with relative paths in the classpath parameter. We don't have control of the Java program. When I directly execute the batch file, the Java program runs successfully.

After confirming the batch file executes successfully, I wrote a Windows service to execute the batch file because we first need to query a db, and then pass the results of the query as arguments to this batch file, and then run this windows service on a schedule.

The first attempt to execute this windows service, I got an error output from the batch file as a result of the java command: *could not find or load main class*. I solved this by changing from relative paths to absolute paths in the **java -cp** option.

**Problem**: Once I solved the classpath problem in the batch file, the java program executed with errors for the same reason: it's trying to read a file from a relative path, but the relative path cannot be found.

Keep in mind, I don't have control of the Java, and the batch file executes successfully when directly double clicked.

**Question**: How can I execute this batch file from C# so that the java program recognizes the relative paths? I tried changing the current working directory in the batch file, before the java command, to align with the relative paths in the java program, but this did not work. What else could I do?

Comment: Did you try changing the working directory of your Windows service to that of the batch file before executing the batch file?`Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Directory.GetParent(@"path\to\batch\file.bat").FullName)`. Also, add some code that shows how you're running the batch file.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, I will give that a try and get back to you probably next week. Unfortunately we can't test the batch file in staging, so I have to go through a prod deployment process to find out if it'll work.

Comment: If you are using `Process.Start` to invoke the batch file, you can specify a `WorkingDirectory` as well, that might be closer to what you're looking for now that I think about it. `Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetParent(@"path\to\batch\file.bat").FullName })`

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes thanks for that additional info. I'm using Process.Start

Comment: @AluanHaddad changing the current working directory to the same as the batch file in C# worked. i can accept your answer if you want to write your comment in an answer.